# rails validate data added via ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a model Bibliography and a model Authors.

When adding a Bibliography, one can get a popup for adding an author.

My question is: how do I validate this and send messages back to the form?

I do that with a `remote` form like so:

```
<%= form_for @author, url: administration_author_createjson_path, remote: true do |f| %>
```

This is in my model:

```
validates :given_name, presence: true
validates :name, presence: true
```

And this is the controller:

```
def createjson
    @author = Author.new(params_auteur)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @author.save
            format.html{}
            format.js{}
            format.json{
                render json: @author, status: :created, location: administration_nouveau_biblio_path
            }
        else
            format.html{ render action: "new"}
            format.json{ render json: @author.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
        end
    end
end
```

The validation works, meaning if the given_name or name are missing, the data isn't saved to the database.

But I don't know how to send the correct messages back to the view in this case.

Comment: What's the relationship between Authors and Bibliography?

Comment: its a habtm relationship.